# A problem in analysis involving arbitrary sets

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets (possibly infinite or uncountable), and $(x_{n,m})_{n \in A, m \in B}$ be a doubly infinite sequence of extended non-negative reals $x_{n,m} \in [0,+\infty]$ indexed by $A$ and $B$. Show that:$$\sum_{(n,m) \in A \times B}x_{n,m}=\sum_{n \in A} \sum_{m \in B} x_{n,m}=\sum_{m \in B} \sum_{n \in A} x_{n,m}$$
I'm fine as long as $A$ and $B$ are both countable (for example, $A=B=\mathbb{N}$). My problem is that I cannot show this if the set $A$ or $B$ (or both) is uncountable.

Comment: You write "sequence" so they are countable.

Comment: Note that if you were to define the sum of uncountably many non-negative values in any sensible way, this sum will always be infinite unless at most countably many of the values are non-zero. Thus you can restrict to the countable case.

Comment: @sigmabe : I think that the author used the word 'sequence' here in a non-technical sense, similar as class or family. This is Exercise 0.0.2 from the book "An introduction to measure theory" by Terry Tao.

Comment: Recall the definition of $\sum\limits_{\alpha \in A} x_\alpha$ for non-negative $x_\alpha$. And to show equality, show that each side is less-than-or-equal to the other side.

Comment: @MeesdeVries : Okay. I get your point. Even if A and B are arbitrary sets, for the sum not to blow up, we must have countable subsets $U \subset A$ and $V \subset B$ such that only $U \times V$ contributes to non-zero values of $x_{n,m}$. Hence it suffices to prove the equalities over $U \times V$.